# Python: Issue running thread which subscribes for a redis channel in a particular machine

Tags: python, redis

I am running this piece of code on centos 6.5. The same code works on my other machine which also has Centos 6.5. I don't understand how this is possible:

```
import redis
import threading
import time

# Singleton class
class Listener(threading.Thread):
    __shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self, r):
        print 'Initing listener'
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.redis = r
        self.pubsub = self.redis.pubsub()

    def list_subscribe(self, channels):
        self.pubsub.subscribe(channels)

    def list_unsubscribe(self, channels):
        self.pubsub.unsubscribe(channels)

    def work(self, item):
        print item['channel'], ":", item['data']

    def run(self):
        print 'Running thread'
        for item in self.pubsub.listen():
            if item['data'] == "KILL":
                self.pubsub.unsubscribe()
                print self, "unsubscribed and finished"
                break
            else:
                print 'Got something'
                self.work(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = redis.Redis()
    client = Listener(r)
    client.start()
    client.list_subscribe(['test'])

    for x in range(0, 10):
        r.publish('test', 'this will reach the listener')
        time.sleep(1)

    r.publish('test', 'KILL')
```

I don't see the printing happening at all. I also added asserts (not shown) and I did not hit any of those.

This is the output I am seeing

```
$ python redis_listener.py 
Initing listener
Running thread
```

This from redis client to confirm that data is actually being published.

```
1425758220.317547 [0 [::1]:36491] "SUBSCRIBE" "test"
1425758220.318266 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758221.319827 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758222.321659 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758223.323464 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758224.325268 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758225.327022 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758226.328722 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758227.329919 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758228.331199 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758229.332095 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "this will reach the listener"
1425758230.333751 [0 [::1]:36492] "PUBLISH" "test" "KILL"
```

How is it possible that the same code works in one machine and doesn't in another?

This is the output from the machine where it "works"

```
Initing listener
Running thread
Got something
test : 1
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
Got something
test : this will reach the listener
<Listener(Thread-1, started 139825429100288)> unsubscribed and finished
```